# Java Extending an Object Except for Some Attributes of Parents

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, cxf

I have a class *C extends B*. and *B extends A*. A has an attribute **name**. I *don't want to see **name** attribute at C class.*

How can I do that ignore?

**PS:** If it is not possible at Java: I am working on a Spring project that uses Apache CXF and has a web service capability. I want to get B type object from client and send C type object to client. Because of my design issues I don't want to change my inheritance mechanism. If there is a way *can I ignore name field at C class*? I am implementing as first-code style.

Comment: @SamirMangroliya I want to access it on B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a class *C extends B*. and *B extends A*. A has an attribute
>   **name**. I *don't want to see **name** attribute at C class.*

Based on your edit, you are trying to hide an attribute from a superclass (A) in the serialized representation of one of it's subclasses (C). Assuming you are using JAX-WS/JAX-RS, you can do this by overriding the property in the subclass and applying annotations to mark it as not eligible for serialization. The primary annotation to apply will be the JAXB annotation @XmlTransient. You can also @JsonIgnore the property, if you are providing the option to serialize objects as JSON. Pseudo code shown below:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class A implements Serializable {
    private String name;

    // ...
}

@XmlRootElement
public class C extends A {

    @Override
    @XmlTransient
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's so helpful for me thanks. However I dont have getters and setter for my class variables. XmlTransient annotation works but how can I make it work on serialization but not at deserialization?

Comment: Add a getter/setter to your subclass, and mark just the getter with @XmlTransient

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `name` field in `A` as `private` and keep both A and B in same Package.

```
package A;
Class A {

 protected String name;

}



Class B extends A{
   // B can access A's attribute
   }



package C;


    Class C extends B{
       // C cannot access name attribute defined in A.
     }
```

And keep C is in a different package.

Comment: In that case B also would not be able to see name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about composition over inheritance. If you need to hide some elements then probably you do not understood properly the Object Oriented code design.

The example provided by you is too narrow to create any better answer. But what is the point of hiding in C when, you can cast it to A and still use it ?

Comment: Actually I want to on the way of oo design however C and B are DTO objects and when an add operation happens I will receive B but if client wants sth. with get I will send C.